# Obtain elevation from latitude longitude coordinates with a simple python script

Tags: python, pandas, gis

I have a python script that I got from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338392/getting-elevation-for-multiple-lat-long-coordinates-in-python?noredirect=1#comment552172_338392) that will pull from the USGS Elevation Point Query Service. However, It keeps timing out and kicks me out after a seemingly random amount of time and before my query finishes. I need another method to pull elevation data given lat lon coordinates.

Here is my current query:

```
# ========= pull elev from usgs server ======

# USGS POINT QUERY SERVICE ==================

url = r'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?'
# ===========================================

# coordinates with known elevation 
lat = [48.633, 48.733, 45.1947, 45.1962]
lon = [-93.9667, -94.6167, -93.3257, -93.2755]

# create df
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat': lat,
    'lon': lon
})

def elevation_function(df, lat_column, long_column):
    elevations = []
    counter = 0
    start = time.time()
    for lat, lon in zip(df[lat_column], df[long_column]):

        # define rest query params
        params = {
            'output': 'json',
            'x': lon,
            'y': lat,
            'units': 'Meters'
        }

        # format query string and return query value
        result = requests.get((url + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))
        elevations.append(result.json()['USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service']['Elevation_Query']['Elevation'])
        counter += 1
        print('Proportion of job complete: {}'.format(round(counter/df.shape[0],3)))
        end = time.time()
        print(str(round(end - start)) + " seconds into job\n")
    df['elev'] = elevations
    return elevations

start = time.time()
count = 0
for i in range(100):
    count += 1
    elevations = elevation_function(df, lat_column='lat', long_column='lon')
end = time.time()

print(str(round(end - start)))
```

Comment: This question was already closed, and then voted to reopen, so don't close it again. /eyeroll!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Streamline the function and add error handling:

- `elevation_function` needs to be written to work with [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

  - Using `apply`, with `axis=1`, automatically iterates through each row of coordinates

#### New Functions:

- `make_remote_request` will continue to make the request until it gets `response`.
- Change the exception to fit the exception returned by the server (e.g. `except (OSError, urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError) as error`)
- Optionally, `import time` and add `time.sleep(5)` before `continue` in the exception, to play nice with the remote server.

```py
def make_remote_request(url: str, params: dict) -> json:
    """
    Makes the remote request
    Continues making attempts until it succeeds
    """

    count = 1
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get((url + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))
        except (OSError, urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError) as error:
            print('\n')
            print('*' * 20, 'Error Occured', '*' * 20)
            print(f'Number of tries: {count}')
            print(f'URL: {url}')
            print(error)
            print('\n')
            count += 1
            continue
        break

    return response


def eleveation_function(x):
    url = 'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?'
    params = {'x': x[1],
              'y': x[0],
              'units': 'Meters',
              'output': 'json'}
    result = make_remote_request(url, params)
    return result.json()['USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service']['Elevation_Query']['Elevation']
```

#### Implement the function

```py
import requests
import urllib
import urllib3
import pandas as pd

# coordinates with known elevation 
lat = [48.633, 48.733, 45.1947, 45.1962]
lon = [-93.9667, -94.6167, -93.3257, -93.2755]

# create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})

     lat      lon
 48.6330 -93.9667
 48.7330 -94.6167
 45.1947 -93.3257
 45.1962 -93.2755

# apply the function
df['elevations'] = df.apply(eleveation_function, axis=1)

     lat      lon  elevations
 48.6330 -93.9667      341.14
 48.7330 -94.6167      328.80
 45.1947 -93.3257      262.68
 45.1962 -93.2755      272.64
```

Comment: Hey @Trenton McKinney Thanks for the help! What does the the make_remote_requestion() syntax                                                                               `-> json:`    do? That should be commented out correct?

Comment: No, those are type annotations.  That means the function returns a JSON.

Comment: The error handling is working fantastic! For the purpose of seeing progress I added `from tqdm import tqdm`
`tqdm.pandas(mininterval=5.,maxinterval=20.)`                                             and instead of `.apply()`  I used `.progress_apply()`

Comment: I was not able to access that URL, as it has been moved.  Instead, I found this one which  worked, however the JSON returned is a little different: [opentopodata example](https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/test-dataset?locations=48.6330,-93.9667)

Comment: @MichaelBehrens You must have done something incorrectly. I just ran it and it worked fine. `https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?` is not the full url. See `response = requests.get((url + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))`

Comment: @MichaelBehrens the base URL that you can get to is `https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/`

Answer (score 0):

Can also pass in params with the following:

```
PARAMS = {'x':x[1], 'y':x[0], 'units':'Feet', 'output':'json'} 
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
```