# Python: Obtaining elevation from latitude and longitude values

Tags: python, json, coordinates, geopandas

Firstly, there is code for this question. However, it seems to only be suitable for the US. As stated on their website (https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/) when unable to find value it will return -1000000, which is my case.

I'm trying to obtain elevation in Sweden.

Using this sample data:

```
lat = [57.728905, 57.728874, 57.728916, 57.728836, 57.728848]
lon = [11.949309, 11.949407, 11.949470, 11.949342, 11.949178]

# create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})
```

**How can I make the code below adaptable to global grounds and not just limited to the US? Or at least, is there a way I could focus it on Sweden? Shouldn't the USGS have global data?**

```
def make_remote_request(url: str, params: dict):
   """
   Makes the remote request
   Continues making attempts until it succeeds
   """

   count = 1
   while True:
       try:
           response = requests.get((url + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))
       except (OSError, urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError) as error:
           print('\n')
           print('*' * 20, 'Error Occured', '*' * 20)
           print(f'Number of tries: {count}')
           print(f'URL: {url}')
           print(error)
           print('\n')
           count += 1
           continue
       break

   return response


def elevation_function(x):
   url = 'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?'
   params = {'x': x[1],
             'y': x[0],
             'units': 'Meters',
             'output': 'json'}
   result = make_remote_request(url, params)
   return result.json()['USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service']['Elevation_Query']['Elevation']
```

To run the function:

```
df['elevation'] = df.apply(elevation_function, axis=1)


# Print output
df
```

Source code: [Obtain elevation from latitude longitude coordinates with a simple python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350063/obtain-elevation-from-latitude-longitude-coordinates-with-a-simple-python-script)

## UPDATE:

Using the suggestions in the accepted answer and adding time.sleep(1) in the elevation function allowed me to get elevation data to all the observations. Note that this API only allows 100 locations per request. Hence, for a higher number of rows, it must be broken down into different requests.

Comment: It is very likely that the service is unable to find data at the requested point you specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using the api from [opentopodata.org](https://www.opentopodata.org/) to obtain elevation values.
You could use the [EU-DEM](https://www.opentopodata.org/datasets/eudem/) dataset which covers entire sweden. An API request is as simple as the following:

```
https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/eudem25m?locations=57.728905,11.949309
```

Another elevation API can be found at https://open-elevation.com/. A request looks very similar:

```
https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?locations=57.728905,11.949309
```

therefore adapting your `elevation_function`:

```
def elevation_function(x):
   url = 'https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/eudem25m?'
   # url = 'https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?'
   params = {'locations': f"{x[0]},{x[1]}"}
   result = make_remote_request(url, params)
   return result.json()['results'][0]['elevation']
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the source! However, I am getting an error:

 ```---> 30     return result.json()['results'][0]['elevation']

KeyError: 'results'```

Comment: your script works for me, so I guess this is most likely caused by the [CORS policy](https://github.com/ajnisbet/opentopodata/issues/9#issuecomment-671472112) of the free API. It blocks cross-origin requests. I've added a different free elevation API endpoint in my answer. never used it before, but it seems to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error:

```
 ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Also, it seemed to take too long just for 4 observations (maybe 2 minutes?). Is this normal?

Comment: yeah, thats odd. it takes that long on my machine too. Nevertheless, using opentopodata.org works like a charm [see here](https://imgur.com/a/3X4LkTQ). did you try to inspect the response? add a print statement in the `elevation_function` like in my image

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how can they tell the allowance if there is no account? By any chance did you need to do this in the past or use an account or something. I can't understand why it works for you and not for me for the same thing...

Comment: In my case, I get True for the first three observations. And an elevation value for those. Then for the final one, like you initially suspected it has some access limitations. The message I get for the last one is: {'error': "Per-second rate limit exceeded for the free hosted API. If you'd like a higher limit or paid managed hosting, send a message to andrew@opentopodata.org.", 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST'} ...

Comment: UPDATE: When using your second API suggestion, I noticed I made a mistake. It doesn't take that long now. However, it rounds the elevation value to 4. In your image, you can see that the elevation values differ slightly. Could I adjust the decimal places or I cannot change that from an API? (First time using one)

Comment: in general you can't expect data from digital elevation models to be that accurate. each dataset has some vertical error. The [EU-DEM](https://land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-dem) for example has 2.9 meters(!) vertical accuracy and on [SRTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission)(which is used by open-elevation.com) the error margin is even higher. So I assume the data does not provide decimal places at all...

Comment: If you want to use the (seemingly) more accurate EU-DEM dataset, you could try to add a second of sleep in between requests to bypass the per-second rate limit of the opentopodata API.

Comment: Just came to update the question and say exactly that! adding time.sleep(1) allowed me to request all the elevations. However, only 100 locations can be done per request. This said, in the presence of a dataframe with 1,000 locations, it must be broken down in 10 requests.